# Sms Sender Confusing

Tags: android, chat

I am new in Eclipse and i have an idea to make app but i didn't get the exact starting point from their tutorials .
My idea is - I want to make an android app that save the number of my classmate or employees of any corporation and then if head control that software it have to add all number in the app (one time) and type message . Then the message send immediately to all of the students or employees for free for head or me . Like way2sms app . It have ability to send sms free to sim card mobile number not internet using text messages chat apps like watsapp and more . 
Then everyone who didn't have android mobile and internet connection will informed easily .
Hope you understand . 
Java sounds for me more powerful and usable all over the world so i turn to Eclipse to make my first app

I found "SmsManager" line on every sms sender tutorial but they use emulator and probably having internet so wats that a way to chat online or send costly(pricing) sms for free like the app i mentioned(way2sms) .

If you have any new way where i start then please submit it here or any other tutorial that really works .

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a free sms, you will at least need a gateway server.

I would advise starting here http://tinjoy23.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/sms-gateway/ for some background info on how to set this up.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lgzShmYGAk I just listen this app and you will try way2sms or search for it in store . I used it they send sms with their name i also want this but they didn't pay for this because the high traffic per in that way they will cost them so many $ and no one paying this to gave free sms . But is there nay socket or something like that i use in java eclipse to make android app ?

Comment: I think you are missing the basic point, someone, somewhere is paying for the service, be it by advertisements or paid sms's.

Comment: hmmm ! i think way2sms have ad plugin so they pay for this OKK ! I never concentrate on that running ads . But as a friend say is it possible by using their api but change sender name !!!??

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friend same kind of idea came into my mind (3 years ago)
in android i was also new at that time but after so much of research i found way to send free sms through android application

see you cant send free sms through mobile to send it you must have sms balance or main balance to send SMS other way is you can send the SMS through third party SMS gateway like Way2SMS, 160by2 and so on there are various free sms gateway present in india you can use their  APIs to do your application after long research i got one site in which that site admin wrote one api in which he integrates all free sms gateways into one API its awsome buddy you must chek this

here is the link of his site 
http://ubaid.tk/
but problem is now this site is in under maintainance
you will get his sample logic api call from below link
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/572203/howplustoplusplussendplusplussmsplususingplusway-s

i tried his API and i got succeess to send free SMS from android application to provided contact number and realy it worked me

best luck buddy

Comment: Wowy, Thanks dear . I want to make my good image in my college so i tried to make it and and gave to head sir to inform everyone for free . Hope you understand . And one more thing can i customize the sender name like a private name and can i add so many contacts to send message all of them in same time .. Thanks . Will you please add me in facebook so i can understand how to use it . www.facebook.com/jeevanjot.singh.vital

Comment: yes you can customize as per your requirement but listen for Way2SMS there is limit of 160 character some other apis am not sure i think indiarocks or fullonsms gateway provides limit more than 160 character and to hit the webservice or api for only that instance user need internet connection cause then only your contacts will goto that api and background logic will send your message to your provided contact list

Comment: Will you please add me in facebook so i can understand how to use it . www.facebook.com/jeevanjot.singh.vital   
I am a Beginner in Eclipse Android Sdk and i love this OS . Please can you guide me how i add this or how use . Add me using my facebook url